# How I can add div to menu?

Tags: php, functions, menus, sub-menu

I have div structure

```
<div class = 'main-menu'>
 <ul class = 'menu'>
  <li class = 'item1'></li>
  <li class = 'item2'></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

But I want add div to menu

```
<div class = 'main-menu'>
 <ul class = 'menu'>
  <li class = 'item1'></li>
  <li class = 'item2'>
   <div class="adv_categories" id="adv_categories">
     <?php cp_create_categories_list( 'menu' ) ?>
   </div>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using  wp_nav_menu you can pass arguments to it which help you style the output, look at:

- `$container` Whether to wrap the ul, and what to wrap it with. Allowed tags are div and nav. Use false for no container e.g. container => false .
- `$container_class` the class that is applied to the container.
- `$container_id` The ID that is applied to the container.
- `$menu_class` CSS class to use for the containing div element which forms the default menu, or the ul element when a custom menu is configured in the admin interface.
- `$before` Output text before the of the link.
- `$after` Output text after the of the link.
- `$link_before` Output text before the link text.
- `$link_after` Output text after the link text.
- `$items_wrap` Whatever to wrap the items with an ul, and how to wrap them with.

So in you case you can use

```
array( 'link_before' => '<div class="your_class">' , 'link_after' => '</div>');
```

But if you ask me you can probably do what you want with the classes WordPress prints out anyway.

[http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items](http://wordpressgeekhelp.blogspot.com/2015/08/function-referencewp-get-nav-menu-items.html)

Comment: It is not that I want. Your solution just wraps link to div.

Answer (score 0):

For this type of result, you need to get your hands dirty and use a [custom nav menu walker](https://www.google.com/search?ei=WOBtWteNOsKuUtCmvvAG&q=wordpress%20create%20custom%20nav%20menu%20walker) that will give you full control of the output the menu produces. There are many intricacies involved regarding how you plan to handle multiple levels in the menu (are you going for top level only?).

From what I see, you don't want to just wrap menu items, but also want to insert multiple menu items.

You could also give the `'walker_nav_menu_start_el'` [filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/walker_nav_menu_start_el/) a go as it gives you access to the link output and you could add markup before the output.